# 選択範囲の上下に文字列を挿入する方法

Tags: emeditor

画像左の選択状態の時にマクロ実行で、
画像右の結果を得たいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`<li></li>`の挿入のマクロは下ですが、
`document.selection.Replace("(.*●.*)","<li>\\1</li>",eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);`

選択範囲の上下にを挿入する方法が分かりません。

実現方法はあるでしょうか。
もしよろしければ書き方を教えてほしいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

選択範囲の上下に指定文字列を挿入するマクロです。

```
    CombineHistory = true;
    var x1 = document.selection.GetTopPointX(eePosLogical);
    var y1 = document.selection.GetTopPointY(eePosLogical);
    var x2 = document.selection.GetBottomPointX(eePosLogical);
    var y2 = document.selection.GetBottomPointY(eePosLogical);
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, x2, y2 );
    document.writeln( "</div>" );   // 選択範囲の下側に挿入したい文字列
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, x1, y1 );
    document.writeln( "<div>" );    // 選択範囲の上側に挿入したい文字列
    CombineHistory = false;
```

他のユーザーのためにマクロを実行する方法を書きますと、以下の通りです。

1. 上記のマクロを、適当なファイル名、例えば `InsertDiv.jsee` という名前で、UTF-16 (BOM付き) または UTF-8 (BOM付き) のエンコードで保存します。
2. EmEditor の [マクロ] メニューの [選択] から、保存したマクロを選択します。
3. 編集したいテキスト ファイルを開き、そのファイルがアクティブ状態で、[マクロ] メニューの [実行] (または <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) を選択します。すると、マクロが実行されます。

Comment: なるほど、カーソル位置を利用するのですね。
望む結果が得られました。
コードを書いて頂き、ありがとうございます。